# Make a Typo3 website go LIVE

Tags: php, mysql, configuration, typo3

I am just trying to publish a website from a test server ([www.mobileglas.tryit.ch](http://mobileglas.tryit.ch/)) to a live server ([www.mobileglas.ch](http://mobileglas.ch/)).

**Things that I have done:**

- I have downloaded the files from the test server and uploaded them on
  the live server.
- I have downloaded the sql file from the test server,
  removed "tryit." from all URLs and uploaded the sql file on the new
  server (phpMyAdmin).
- I have changed the details to the database
  connection in the file localconf.php.

Now when you go to [mobileglas.ch](http://mobileglas.ch/), you see the message "Unable to connect to database.".

The weird thing is, the backend ([mobileglas.ch/typo3](http://mobileglas.ch/typo3)) is working great. I only get this message on the frontend. How could this be??

I am using this code to debug but it is still not showing me any more information.

```
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['SYS']['displayErrors'] = '1';
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['SYS']['enable_errorDLOG'] = '1';
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['SYS']['enable_exceptionDLOG'] = '1';
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['SYS']['sqlDebug'] = '1';
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['SYS']['enable_DLOG'] = '1';
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['FE']['debug'] = '1';
```

Comment: Debug your code and you will find it out how.

Comment: @Shadow how? Where to start? What to do?

Comment: How did you develop the site if you do not know how to debug?

Comment: @Shadow I didn't develop this site. I am just trying to move it to another server.

Comment: Then contact the developer and ask him/her to help you. Without code you will not get help on SO. If you do not know how to code, you cannot find the relevant code sections either, so you will not be able to share code with us. This will result in your question being closed.

Comment: @Shadow the code is the same as in the test server and as you see the website works great on the test server. So I don't think that it's something wrong with the code. I guess there must be something wrong with the database or the configuration.

Comment: But debugging the code would tell you the exact technical error message, not just a meaningless, general stuff reserved for end users.

Comment: @Shadow I have updated my post. But the code is still not helping me.

Comment: What do you get? An "oops, an error occurred" page? A blank page? In the first case, try to log in into the TYPO3 backend in another tab in the same browser, then the error message gets more verbose. In the latter case, check the PHP error log. Also, you are probably using an age-old version of TYPO3, think about an update (which is probably non-trivial, you should probably get help for it).

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I had to change the database connection details for each extension (not very smart from the developer).